# React Component Sharing on Azure Artifacts

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I need a React component sharing solution so components that I use in multiple applications keep synced. Let's say I have a TopBar component in 1 app of 10 apps I have, all of the rest apps would get the updated TopBar component. There are solutions like Bit.dev made for this job but, is it possible to do this using Azure Artifacts?

Note: To my understanding, Azure Artifacts is for packages and what I am looking to accomplish is component sharing, these are two totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Artifacts is a universal store for all the artifacts which you can use as part of development and deployment, includes NuGet, npm, Maven packages and Universal Packages.Azure Artifacts manages the dependencies used in your codebase and provides easy tools to ensure the immutability and performance of those components.

In your scenario, you can package your TopBar component as an Azure Artifacts and publish the artifact. Please follow this document to [use npm to store JavaScript packages in Azure DevOps Services or TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/get-started-npm?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows).